# Accessing _embedded in Json Response

Tags: json, angular, typescript, spring-data-jpa

Trouble accessing the _embedded property in Json in Angular. Is it even possible?
Json response created using Spring-Data-Jpa looks like this:

```
{
"_embedded": {
    "reviews": [
        {
            "author": "Anonymous",
            "content": "This movie sucks",
            "upvotes": 0,
            "downvotes": 0,
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/reviews/1"
                },
                "review": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/reviews/1"
                },
                "film": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/reviews/1/film"
                }
            }
        }, ...
    ]
},
"_links": {
    "self": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/reviews{?page,size,sort}",
        "templated": true
    },
    "profile": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/profile/reviews"
    }
},
"page": {
    "size": 20,
    "totalElements": 6,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "number": 0
}
```

}
From my Client app I would like to process reviews nested in the embedded field. However I cannot get to the _embedded property. My Angular Service looks like this:

```
getEmbedded(): Observable<any> {
return this.http.get(ServerConfig.serverAddress + '/api/reviews');
}
```

Component using the service:

```
export class ReviewListComponent implements OnInit {
embeddedReviewResource: any;

constructor(private reviewService: ReviewService) { }

ngOnInit() {

this.reviewService.getEmbedded().subscribe(data => {
  this.embeddedReviewResource = data;
});
}
```

I tried referncing the _embedded property in a number of ways in my view:

```
*ngFor="let review of embeddedReviewResource.reviews
```

or

```
*ngFor="let review of embeddedReviewResource._embedded.reviews
```

or

```
*ngFor="let review of embeddedReviewResource.getEmbedded().reviews
```

or

```
*ngFor="let review of embeddedReviewResource._embeddedViews.reviews
```

None of theses seems to do the trick. How can I access _embedded property  in the Json File?
Full source code is available at [my GitHub](https://github.com/jslowbro/FilmBoxAngular).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   reviews = []; 

   this.reviewService.getEmbedded().subscribe(data => {
      this.reviews = data._embedded.reviews;
    });
```

template

```
   <div *ngFor="let review of reviews"> 
     {{ review.content }}
   </div>
```